# Install Ubuntu’s Web Apps Feature (12.04, FF15)

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

My problem is just as described in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187311/cant-install-unity-webapps-preview) - I can't install Ubuntu's web apps because it depends on FF14 (but Ubuntu comes shipped with FF15 already (at least the mentioned thread says so)).

That's pretty annoying as I'm not even using FF (I use Chromium). Migrating from Windows, I'm fairly afraid of removing the Browser the OS was shipped with.

My questions:

- Can I remove FF just like that?

  - If so, how?
- ***Would that solve the issue?***

  - If so, any other suggestions?